# How to present UIAlertController from SKScene

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I'm working in Spritekit and I'm trying to present a UIAlertController from my SKScene, but I am having trouble doing it. I've watched several tutorials but none of the UIAlertController tutorials have been specific to Spritekit. I keep seeing this code below, but it has not been effective since SKScene is not a UIViewController.

```
[self presentViewController:self animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I have the rest of the relative code below. Can anybody please help me present my UIAlerController on my SKScene.

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"You Lose!" message:@"Do You Want To Beat This Level?" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *CancelButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"GiveUp" style:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert handler:<#^(UIAlertAction *action)handler#>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SKScene` instance can't invoke `presentViewController(_:animated:completion)` because it is not a subclass of `UIViewController`. However, if you rewrite as such, your alert will launch:

```
self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

ps: there will be a warning though that `Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fc31eb32e50>  on <Sample_Game.GameViewController: 0x7fc31bd9b4f0> which is already presenting`. If anyone knows how to eradicate this warning, that will be great.

---

[Updated 11 August 2016]

To eradicate the aforementioned warning, check if the rootViewController has presented a view controller:

```
 let vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
 if vc.presentedViewController == nil {
    vc.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

SKScene shouldn't be the one presenting the UIAlertController, but rather a UIViewController such as your initial GameViewController. Above code works fine when called from a UIViewController.

You could use NSNotificationCenter to help you call your view controller.

Add this to your view controller's viewDidLoad method,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self                                          
                                         selector:@selector(playerLost:) 
                                             name:@"PlayerLostNotification" 
                                           object:nil];
```

and you will need to define this method too.

```
- (void)playerLost:(NSNotification*) notification {
   UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"You Lose!" 
                                         message:@"Do You Want To Beat This Level?" 
                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

   UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"GiveUp"
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                       handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                          [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                       }];
   [alert addAction:cancel];
   [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

In your SKScene when the player loses,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PlayerLostNotification" object:self];
```

Comment: But in the context of my game, when the player loses, I use the UIAlertController to give the user the option to play the level again or give up and go to the menu (I was using UIAlertView previously). How can I perform that from the SKScene?

Comment: Right on. Essentially you would need to relay a message back to the view controller. You could keep a reference to the view controller in SKScene, make a delegate, or use NSNotificationCenter. Essentially you want to call the view controller when it is time to show the alert.

Comment: Would you mind writing an example in code of how I would do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just set a pointer to your viewController when you create your scene. Then you can call it like this:
    [self.viewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

In your ViewController:

```
// Create and configure the scene.
GameScene *scene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:viewSize];
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
scene.viewController = self;

// Present the scene.
[skView presentScene:scene];
```